# Custom shape for border radius image in React-Native

Tags: css, react-native, styled-components

I want to reproduce that style in my component (the border bottom).
I am basically loading a rectangular image, then I want to rounded it at the bottom.

[image]

I think about :

- border-bottom-right-radius and left, but it is not accurate with the custom shape of the screen.
- transform scaleX, but it scale the image proportion (obviously)
- create a white image with the custom shape and load it at the bottom of the screen, but I want to add a shadow at the bottom of the image... With a white image I could not do that...

Is there a way to do that in a proper style with React-Native ?

Thank you !

Comment: Is it close enough to what you want ? *border-radius: 100%/0 0 20% 20%*
`

Comment: It does not seem possible in react-native to applicate : borderRadius: 100%/0 0 20% 20%; property...

Comment: Oh my bad, sorry. I won't be able to help then, good luck.

Comment: I edited my answer to show a drop shadow (works for the bottom of image only).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible, but it's a little tricky. The idea is you need to create a "mask" of sorts that you can apply the shape to. After doing that you can put the image as a child of the mask element so that it will essentially mask the area you want. It's probably possible to do it with a dynamic size, but I didn't take the time to come up with that solution, i'll leave that to you ;)

Hopefully this'll get you going in the right direction though.

First lets setup the app structure

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.app}>
        <Mask />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Pretty straightforward, just a basic app with a mask component. I made it a component so you can pass props to it in the future (like the image uri for instance).

Then the mask component

```
const logoUri = `http://66.media.tumblr.com/86b941b3445b80a518ea51208f48ab35/tumblr_ntpi99a6Pl1uounv1o1_500.png`;
const Mask = (props) => (
  <View style={styles.maskContainer}>
    <View style={styles.mask}>
      <Image
        source={{ uri: logoUri }}
        style={styles.img}
      />
    </View>
  </View>
)
```

The `maskContainer` is a positioning element to help center the image. 
The `mask` uses the [oval style approach](https://codedaily.io/tutorials/22/The-Shapes-of-React-Native) but to get the edges to not round like border radius, we have to scale it 2x 
The `img` style needs to reverse the scaling so that the image itself is not warped :)

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  app: {
    marginHorizontal: "auto",
    maxWidth: 500,
    backgroundColor: "#e0e0e0",
    width: 700,
    height: 700
  },
  mask: {
    width: 200,
    height: 470,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 100,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 100,
    overflow: "hidden",
    transform: [{ scaleX: 2 }]
  },
  img: {
    height: 470,
    width: 299,
    left: 25,
    position: "absolute",
    transform: [{ scaleX: 0.5 }, { translate: "-50%" }]
  },
  maskContainer: {
    position: "absolute",
    left: "50%",
    transform: [{ translate: "-50%" }]
  }
});
```

#### [**See it working on this fiddle!**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-drx06)

Comment: Thank you ! It helps me to visualize how to do it, but it is not totally accurate for React-Native... :/

Answer (score 0):

@John Ruddell's answer is very helpful.
I am able to design this by creating a mask and applied through SVG path. So, you need to install 2 libraries.

1. [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg) (`expo install react-native-svg`)
2. [react-native-masked-view](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-masked-view) (`npm install --save @react-native-community/masked-view`)

Following code respect the aspect ratio of image. So, you need the set the aspect ratio of your image and adjust the value of `curveAdjustment` in order to achieve your desired sharpness of curve.

```
      import React from "react";
      import {
        Image,
        View,
        StyleSheet,
        Text,
        useWindowDimensions,
      } from "react-native";

      import MaskedView from "@react-native-community/masked-view";
      import Svg, { Path } from "react-native-svg";

      const logoUri = `http://66.media.tumblr.com/86b941b3445b80a518ea51208f48ab35/tumblr_ntpi99a6Pl1uounv1o1_500.png`;

      function SplashScreen(props) {
        const windowWidth = useWindowDimensions().width;

        const imageAspectWidth = 375;
        const imageAspectHeight = 332;

        const curveAdjustment = 40;
        const maskHeight = (imageAspectHeight / imageAspectWidth) * windowWidth;

        const scaleFactor = imageAspectWidth / imageAspectHeight;
        const scaledHeight = scaleFactor * maskHeight;

        const controlPointX = windowWidth / 2.0;
        const controlPointY = scaledHeight + curveAdjustment;

        const curveCenterPointY = (controlPointY - maskHeight) / 2;

        return (
          <View style={styles.main}>
            <MaskedView
              style={[
                styles.mask,
                {
                  height: controlPointY - curveCenterPointY,
                },
              ]}
              maskElement={
                <Svg height="100%" width="100%">
                  <Path
                    d={`M0 0 L${windowWidth} 0 L${windowWidth} ${maskHeight} Q${controlPointX} ${controlPointY} 0 ${maskHeight} Z`}
                    fill={"#fff"}
                  />
                </Svg>
              }
            >
              <Image source={{ uri: logoUri }} style={styles.image} />
            </MaskedView>
            <Text>{"Tag line"}</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }

      const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        image: {
          flex: 1,
          resizeMode: "stretch",
        },
        main: {
          flex: 1,
        },
        mask: {
          backgroundColor: "orange",
          width: "100%",
        },
      });

      export default SplashScreen;
```

## Final result

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score -2):

Yep. clip-path property!

Just add: 
clip-path: circle(69.3% at 50% 30%)

To your class and it will work.

if you want to create it yourself, there's a generator here:
https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/