# Image boarder with curved edges in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I need to design an image with a Curved Border.
I have tried

`borderBottomRightRadius: 50, borderBottomLeftRadius: 50`

But this is not what I want.
I need similar to the background Image in this ref Image

[image]

Comment: @Azem Ahamed have look on this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56270012/custom-shape-for-border-radius-image-in-react-native , this is your question's answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom shape for border radius image in React-Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56270012/custom-shape-for-border-radius-image-in-react-native)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this style codes with scale and you have an ellipse. width is screen width. You can take it using Dimensions API.

```
 const {width} = Dimensions.get('window');
```

- 

```
    width: "100%",
    height: 200,
    borderBottomRightRadius: width / 2,
    borderBottomStartRadius: width / 2,
    transform:[{scaleX: 2}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but , when I use the resize mode property (streatch, cover) to fit in the image it doesn't suit.

Comment: You can give a transform:[{scaleX: 0.5}] to your image. Also, inside of the curved viev.